# Is a document compiled with pdfLaTeX which includes a Form environment (hyperref) likely to compatible with the standard Linux pdf viewer?

Tags: hyperref, document-classes, linux, forms

I'll offer the disclaimer that, in my question, I may have been stretching the truth when I said `a' Form environment.  The Form environment is implemented in a .cls file to which there are multiple calls in the main document.  I likely have multiple forms in one document, so this may be the issue.

The document/form functionality works across various viewers on my W7 machine.  Linux users have informed me that it does not work there.

At the tex end, is there anything specific that I should consider doing to ensure compatibility with Linux users / all platforms?

Comment: It depends on the viewer. Not all are compliant. *Ensuring* compatibility with all platforms is an impossible task -- all you can do is ensure you're compliant to the standard. (Though there are some things that are notoriously not implemented, like JavaScript and other similarly interactive media. Documents that use those are rare, though.)

Comment: If you could please provide an MWE, we could help you more.

Comment: Linux users can install `acroread`. It is pretty dire, but it does work mostly, albeit excruciatingly slowly. Note that the latest version is verion 9 so anything that relies on newer features won't work. In more standard (and nicer) viewers, it varies. In my experience, simple forms work fine. Form boxes, for example. Things like radio buttons and drop-down menus and the like are another story. Those may or may not work or may work partially and/or display very oddly. This is the last time I tried it. Mostly, I just use text boxes which work fine. (And you can save/print annotated PDFs!)

Comment: One of my LaTeX books contains an overview of this in the section [Electronic PDF Forms](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/html/eforms.shtml). The only support Adobe seems to have for Linux is for the 32bit variety. I have x86_64 Fedora and `acroread` doesn't work at all. (I've tried it with wine as well, but it crashes.)